# Ramanujan's personification of small positive integers

Tags: elementary-number-theory, reference-request, intuition, math-history

I dimly recall reading somewhere (perhaps in "The Man Who Knew Infinity"?) that Ramanujan associated personalities (perhaps it was mystical personalities, e.g. specific gods and goddesses?) with small positive integers. Is there a list of of which numbers were associated by him with which personalities?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to *The Man Who Knew Infinity*, Ramanujan dealt with the quantity $2^n-1$. According to him:

When $n=0$, the expression denotes nothing.

When $n=1$, the expression denotes unity, the Infinite God.

When $n=2$, the expression denotes Trinity, the [three demigods](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Demigod#Hindu) of Hindus: Brahma, Vishnu, and Maheswar (Shiva).

When $n=3$, the expression denotes [Sapta Rishis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saptarishi).

For further reading see, *Ramanujan Memorial Number, Vol. 1, Letters and Reminiscences* and *Ramanujan Memorial Number, Vol. 2, An Inspiration*, Madras: Muthailpet High School by P. K. Srinivasan.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Bhutasamkhya_system&oldid=545866328 — using things there are $n$ of, to denote the number $n$, was a standard practice in classical Indian mathematics. I'm not sure whether Ramanujan had encountered any classical Indian mathematics though, so I have a tiny suspicion that the author of _The Man Who Knew Infinity_ just got things a bit mixed up. (Or maybe Ramanujan did arrive at the same convention by himself; we know he did that with a lot of mathematics!)